# Java Exception when Adding Items to an Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
package survival;

public class World {
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private int distancePenalty = 2;
    private int turnPenalty = 4;
    private double hungerPenalty = 0.1;

    private Plant[] plants;
    private Herbivore[] herbivores;
    private Carnivore[] carnivores;

    private int[] newestHerbivore;
    private int[] newestCarnivore;

    public World(int plantNumber, int herbivoreNumber, int carnivoreNumber, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        plants = new Plant[plantNumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < plantNumber; i++) {
            plants[i] = new Plant(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);
        }        
        herbivores = new Herbivore[herbivoreNumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < herbivoreNumber; i++) {
            herbivores[i] = new Herbivore(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);

            //////////// This line causes java.lang.NullPointerException
            newestHerbivore[i] = 1;
        }
        carnivores = new Carnivore[carnivoreNumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < carnivoreNumber; i++) {

            //////////// This line causes java.lang.NullPointerException
            newestCarnivore[i] = 1;
        }        
    }
}
```

Why is this line:

```
newestHerbivore[i] = 1;
```

an element causing an exception?

Comment: newestHerbivore array is empty, so assigning values based on index will throw error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the array before you assign to it:

```
herbivores = new Herbivore[herbivoreNumber];
newestHerbivore = new int[herbivoreNumber];
```

BTW: arrays are cumbersome and inflexible. In Java, you should use Collections instead. In most cases, ArrayLists will do fine as a replacement for array code.

Comment: How would you change it to use what you've mentioned?

Comment: @ConnerRuhl Read the [Collections Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), that should get you started

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the `newestHerbivore` array, so trying to assign to its element triggers an NPE.

The same goes for `newestCarnivore`.

I think the following wording in your question might explain the confusion: *why is **adding** an element...* You are not *adding* an element, you're *changing the value* of an existing element. In your case, the element doesn't exist since the array reference is `null` (in essence, the entire array doesn't exist).

The exact purpose of these two arrays is not clear, so I hesitate to offer a suggestion on how to fix this. My guess -- based on the names of the two variables and on your comments -- would be that they should really be scalar variables rather than arrays.

Comment: @ConnerRuhl: It's declared, but not initialized, so it contains `null`.

Comment: @ConnerRuhl declared, but not initialized

Comment: The program will simulate an evolutionary environment, the arrays keep track of the last type of organism that mated.